# How can I change my textView more editable should I editText instead?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

As u can see in my calculator app it can add or delete text or number only at the end, since I'm using textView. Is there an alternative where I can edit from any position that uses buttons I provided instead of the default.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnFYw.png)

Comment: if you want to edit from any position better to use editText because text view is View of all  type text  .

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use edit text or you can use an edit text in a dialog. Once you click on the texrview a dialog with edittext will show up so user can edit from there, than set the textview   from string of edittext. This would be programmatic with no xml edits.

```
dia.setMessage("yourmessage");
final EditText edittext1 = new 
EditText(MainActivity.this); 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams
Ipar = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams
(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
edittext1.setLayoutParams(Ipar);
dia.setView(edittext1);
if (!textview1.equals("")) {
edittext1.setText((textview1.getText()));
} dia.setPositiveButton("O", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which) {
    textview1.setText((edittext1.getText()));
    
}
});
dia.setNegativeButton("X", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which) {
    
}
});
dia.create().show();
```